# Quickest way to get currently provisioned throughput for all collections in an account?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell

I would like to gather information about currently provisioned throughput for all (Mongo API) collections in all databases in a Cosmos account. This is to detect any variances from an expected baseline.

For my use case the results need to report autoscale but not database provisioned throughput.

The following works but is quite slow (I ran it in Azure cloudshell for an account with 94 collections across 41 databases. The first attempt took 4 mins 48 seconds with some noticeable lengthy delays between some of the results. The second attempt was 3 minutes faster at 1 min 48.

Even the second attempt is much too slow for my liking though.

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription "..."

$rgName = "..."
$accountName = "..."

Get-AzCosmosDBMongoDBDatabase -ResourceGroupName $rgName -AccountName $accountName | ForEach-Object {$Dbname = $_.Name; Get-AzCosmosDBMongoDBCollection -ResourceGroupName $rgName -AccountName $accountName  -Database  $Dbname | ForEach-Object {$collName = $_.Name; Get-AzCosmosDBMongoDBCollectionThroughput -ResourceGroupName $rgName -AccountName $accountName -DatabaseName $Dbname -Name $collName |  Select-Object -Property Throughput, MinimumThroughput,@{Name = 'DatabaseName'; Expression = {$Dbname}},@{Name = 'CollectionName'; Expression = {$collName}} -ExpandProperty AutoscaleSettings}}
```

Is there any way of getting the desired results much quicker than the above?

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly try using the [Azure Management Library for Cosmos DB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.CosmosDB/) but I can't say for sure this would be any faster. There is a sample on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-management-net/blob/master/cosmos-management-generated/MongoDB.cs) that can show you how to enumerate through database and collection objects and get the throughput on each.

The challenge here overall is control plane operations in Cosmos are served by a master partition within the account and it has an extremely small amount of RU/s to service requests. In fact, if you make too many meta data requests to this master partition you can get rate limited and receive 429 responses. The fact that this is taking such a long period of time is likely a good thing in that you aren't seeing 429s.

Comment: Thanks. Another possibility I'm considering is requesting the ProvisionedThroughput and AutoscaleMaxThroughput from AzureMonitor for all databases and collections. This will certainly be much quicker to get the results. Does have some down sides in complexity and unreliable casing of names though